# Dynamic change in the value of spinner

Tags: android, spinner, visible

I have 2 Spinnery which holds some value (the same in the two spinners). How do to the value of 1 Spinner were not visible in 2 spinner? If you select a value of 1 spinnerze she is to be seen in the 2nd.

Comment: could got you , did you mean that you have two spinner and when you select a value in the first one, the values in the second one have to change ?

Comment: Exactly, the value of one spinner may be at 2 spinner and needs to be updated

Answer (score 0):

#### java activity class StackActivity.java

```
package com.stack.question;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class StackActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner spinner1, spinner2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] { "data1",
                        "data2" });
        adapterType
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapterType);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapterType);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        StackActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {
                                "roma", "milan" });
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```